# how to install inkscape in Mac OS X 10.9.1

Tags: macos, install, x11

I need help installing `inkscape` on My MAC OS X 10.9.1

I have followed http://www.inkscape.org/en/download/mac-os/ to install inkscape

but not able to run inkscape and facin problem for x11 preferences

please help through installing inkscape in my mac os X 10.9.1

Comment: Do you have X11 installed on your Mac ?

Comment: no how to install that? I am new to mac

Answer (score 2):

You need an X.Org application. It will automatically launch when you start Inkscape. Apple used to ship one called `X11.app`.  Now your best bet is [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/).

Answer (score 1):

In the Inkspace download page, the instruction is very clear. You can download the X11 app from the link given in that page.After installation you can have the Preference window as shown in that page.

Direct link to the file
http://xquartz.macosforge.org/downloads/SL/XQuartz-2.7.5.dmg